# Trouble with PHP session based login system

Tags: php, html, session

So I'm trying to get a simple session based login working, and my sessions aren't being saved at all. I've tried many things, but nothing works! Please help!

Edit: added start_session, but it is still empty

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

...

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result);

                            $_SESSION['id']= $row[0];
                            $_SESSION['uname'] = $row[1];
                            $_SESSION['pass'] = $row[2];
                            session_write_close(); <-- now removed, but the session is still empty


                            echo  $row[1] . "Login accepted.<br />";
```

This is the code to create the session. all the rows are accounted for, and the code is being called, but the session still turns out empty.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['uname'])) echo 'empty session';
```

Also, to note that firebug says 0 objects stored in sessionstorage.

Comment: do you call session_start() before using $_SESSION ?

Comment: I do now, but the session's still empty

Comment: @CyanPrime see my updated answer for a simple test script to answer your revised question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9412982/461813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remove `session_write_close()`

[`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/session_write_close) ends the session:

> End the current session and store session data.

Any subsequent calls to `$_SESSION` will not return any data as the session has been written and then closed.

Generally you would not call `session_write_close()` until just before you perform a `header('Location: http://example.org')` redirect. As this is not the case in your code you should remove it.

### Ensure you are calling `session_start()`

I am assuming that you are calling `session_start()` at the top of all your scripts.

### Test your session

To test that your session is working then I suggest implementing the following test script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'Hello';
echo $_SESSION['test'] . ' World!';
// you should get: Hello World!
```

This way you know that there is definitely something in your session array. In your sample code your are getting your data from a database, which might be returning empty values.

### PHP session and HTML5 sessionstorage confusion

They are not one and the same thing. PHP's sessions are stored on the server whereas the browser stores HTML5 sessionstorage locally in the browser. The HTML5 sessionstorage is a client side store of information that only lasts for that session. See the [w3c specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute) for more information.

PHP's `$_SESSION` does not get stored or affect data in the HTML5 sessionstorage.

Comment: removed session_write_close() and added session_start to the top of my code, but it still isn't working.

Comment: it did echo out hello world, but firebug still said 0 items in sessionstorage. Also to note, if I print out the session name in my login page, I get the proper name. But still 0 items in sessionstorage

Comment: @CyanPrime I have updated my answer to reflect this problem you are having. sessionstorage is entirely different to PHP's sessions.

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php:

> End the current session and store session data.
>
> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without
>   the need to call session_write_close() [...]

You're closing the session prematurely and storing the data, which obviously doesn't allow your data to be retained for the call inside the if.

You also forgot to call `session_start()` (or to include it in the piece of code you posted).

Comment: removed session_write_close() and added session_start to the top of my code, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can begin storing user information in your PHP session, you must first start the session. When you start a session, it must be at the very beginning of your code, before any HTML or text is sent.

e.g.

```
<?php
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 
?>
```

This tiny piece of code will register the user's session with the server, allow you to start saving user information and assign a UID (unique identification number) for that user's session.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. Apparently I have to call start_session() at the top of ANY PAGE THAT USES SESSION INFORMATION and not just the page that creates the session. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it. Please consider marking my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9412982/461813) as the fix.